# SCT-013-000 Calibration Value

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

I have an [SCT-013-000](https://www.elecrow.com/download/SCT013-000_datasheet.pdf) connected to my ESP32 microcontroller and I am having problems setting the calibration value. I'm using the following scheme with 2 10K resistors and one 22 resistor with a 10uF capacitor. I've seen in some that the count of your calibration value would be 90.9090, however when using this I only gain inexact values. Can you help me please?

[image]

***Pretend that microprocessor is the ESP32 and its inputs and the DC motor is the SCT.***

Comment: Whatever an SCT-013 is, please link to its datasheet, and add a proper schematic of your circuit.

Comment: Isnt the max allowed load val 10 ohm instead of 22 ?  Also, what range of values are you getting in quiet mode and what range are you getting when doing a measurement test ? And what is your test setup ? What you're supposed to get is a nearly stable quiet  measurement about half Vcc and otherwise, upto about 200mV +/- when there is a test current. Also, you have to measure at many times the frequency of the test current. Let us know more about what you're doing and what is happening. Otherwise, we can only sympathize !

Comment: Here a report about : https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/ct-sensors/files/YhdcCTReportIss6.pdf